# Low FPS when running Payday 2

Tags: payday-2

I have noticed that in Payday 2, even at the LOWEST settings, I get ~20-30 fps.

My specs absolutely blow the requirements out of the water.

Here they are:

```
           (My specs | Recommended specs)
 - 3GHz, 2 core cpu  | 2.4GHz, 4 core cpu   (CPU: Core 2 Duo e8400 3GHz)
 - 4 GB DDR3 RAM     | 3 GB RAM
 - Windows 8.1 x64   | XP, Vista or 7
 - Pixel Shader 5    | Pixel Shader 3      (GPU: PNY Quadro 2000 1GB)
 - Vertex Shader 5   | Vertex Shader 3
 - 1 GB VRAM         | 512MB VRAM
```

Why is the game not running when I have WAY more than the specs recommended?
It's not the dual core CPU, as games run faster on faster, fewer cores.

Comment: Please give your full specs, CPU name, GPU name, type of RAM (DDR2, or DDR3?). Recommended specs aren't always the better referencial

Comment: Those aren't "very high" specs, those are barely cutting it specs.

Comment: @memescientist Ok, let me rephrase that, "Very high specs compared to the games reqs" Sorry, but not everyone has the money to go outright and buy a NASA computer for gaming, plus this one was free, so I'm fine with the specs, as all of my games have the FPS measured in the 100's EXCEPT for Payday 2.

Comment: You also imply we need NASA computers to play Payday 2. Not so. My gaming rig cost me something around ~$400 USD, and I can easily run Payday 2 on high settings.

Comment: Your specs compared to the game's recommended specs don't even come close to "blowing them out of the water", heck, it's barely cutting it.  You have just barely enough RAM, only .5 gb more vram, and that's not going to help you much.

Comment: The Quadro 2000 is the equivalent of GTS 450, but with much worse gaming support on a driver level, that's barely even reaching minimum req (8800gt, which is approx same performance as GTS450, but again, the drivers of Quadro gpu's are not optimized for gaming)

Comment: See if the [Lower Shadow Map mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=183841516) helps. You might also want to try the renderer settings (renderer_settings.xml) here: [Kinda Nice Settings for Low-Spec Users](https://www.reddit.com/r/paydaytheheist/comments/2f1nak/kinda_nice_settings_for_lowspec_users/).

Comment: @TheHash-SlingingSlasher to put this as bluntly as possible - payday 2 EATS cpu performance. GPUs are rather irrelevant in comparison. I upgraded my 8core amd fx 8120 to an I 5 4590, and saw an insant FPS boost from 20~ to the cap of 135.

Answer (score 10):

These would be "high-end" specs if you got this computer 5-6 years ago. The computer I built January, 2008 has better performance than this.

There's little that you can do yourself to help this situation. The graphics settings are a complete joke, and likely won't help you with this. One thing that I have noticed to be a *major* help is to reduce your resolution. Going from 1920x1080 to 1600x900 is what jumped me from ~25FPS to ~45FPS on average.

As far as what's causing this, there's two possible bottlenecks in this:

- **Your CPU**. This is the brain of your computer, it's what actually runs the game. A quad-core CPU is recommended, you only have a dual-core CPU. Other factors such as what brand (AMD / Intel), what generation, and what model are all going to play into how well your CPU performs.
- **Your GPU**. This is a special unit dedicated to producing high-quality graphics. Supporting a higher version of the Pixel/Vertex shaders doesn't make it "better". Having more VRAM means you can use higher-quality textures. None of the specs you posted is even relevant to framerate.

> It's not the dual core CPU, as games run faster on faster, fewer cores.

This is just plain **wrong**. While this may be true 5+ years ago, it is certainly not true now. This misconception comes from the fact that many games, especially older games, were not designed with multithreading in mind. For those games, having a faster core was more important than having more cores.

These days however, more and more games are getting the multithreading treatment. Larger game companies have larger budgets, and can afford the time and effort it takes to get the best possible performance. There's simply no excuse these days for a studio to publish a single-threaded game, especially since virtually every platform (PC, Mobile, Console) is practically designed for multithreading.

In your case, I have doubts that the CPU is an issue. This is simply based on my observations during gameplay.

> PNY Quadro 2000 1GB

Here's your problem, a Quadro 2000. That's a workstation card. These cards are generally going to have terrible performance for gaming applications because they weren't designed for gaming in the first place. They were instead designed to accelerate Digital Content Creation.

Get yourself a GPU designed for gaming, and you'll get better performance when gaming.

Comment: +1 about the CPU.  Most games nowadays rely on the GPU to provide most of the computing power, as opposed to the CPU.  So having a lacking GPU and a high powered CPU will do nothing to alleviate your cause

Comment: Likewise, having a great GPU and a crappy CPU will do nothing to help out either

Comment: @memescientist The CPU is still important! I recently upgraded a friend's computer by slapping an FX-8350 in to replace the stock CPU that came with his build, and we got a noticable 5-6 FPS boost with nothing else changed. Better components will always mean better performance; but as you've said, completely lacking in one area is going to be extremely detrimental either way.

Comment: I know the CPU's important, just that it's not as important as it was maybe a few years ago in regards to the latest games.  Some new games that have come out recently are heavily GPU-dependent, but also need a good CPU to work well.